# change column numbers in a csv file

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

I have a pipe delimited file with 3 columns

```
aaa|xyz|pqr
another|column
with
line break | last column
```

The expected output is :

```
aaa|xyz|pqr
another|column with line break | last column
```

If I remove the line breaks then I get a single line like this...

```
aaa|xyz|pqr another|column with line break | last column
```

But I need 3 columns on each line.

Comment: awk is a UNIX tool which is record oriented, not line oriented.

Answer (score 2):

Python solution:

```
import sys

def fix_rows(it, n):
    row = ''
    for line in it:
        if row:
            row = row.rstrip('\n') + ' ' + line
        else:
            row = line
        if row.count('|') == n - 1:
            yield row
            row = ''
    if row:
        yield row

with open('a.csv') as f:
    sys.stdout.writelines(fix_rows(f, 3))
```

output:

```
aaa|xyz|pqr
another|column with line break | last column
```

Comment: There should be space between "column with line" and I am getting 2 extra lines when I tried this code. ("column" and "columnwith")

Comment: @shantanuo, I updated the code and output accordingly.

Comment: You have the positional argument `it` in `fix_rows` but then refer to the global `f` inside of `fix_rows`. I think you intended `for line in it:` no?

Comment: @dawg, You're right. I appreciate your pointing. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk -F'|' 'NF!=3{ line=line ? line " " $0 : $0; c=split( line, arr, "|"); if(c == 3){ $0=line; }else{ next } }1' yourfile
```

More readable `awk` version:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
          FS="|";
}

NF!=3{ 
          line=line ? line " " $0 : $0; 
          c=split( line, arr, "|"); 
          if(c == 3) {
                     $0=line; 
          }
          else { 
                     next;
          }
}1
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NF!=3{ line=line ? line " " $0 : $0; c=split( line, arr, "|"); if(c == 3){ $0=line; }else{ next } }1' yourfile
aaa|xyz|pqr
another|column with line break | last column
```

It is working for your sample input.

Comment: You tend to give good answers... but without any explanation of the code to make them even better.

Comment: I agree with @fedorqui , the readable awk version would get better with inline comments on the steps (the inline if/else assignment is not trivial for newcomers for exemple)

Comment: what is this line=line ? line " " $0 : $0; @sat I've already upvoted your solution

Comment: @josifoski, It is a ternary operator. `condition? if true: if false`. Here, if `line` is not empty, then concatenate `line` and `$0`. Else, just store the `$0`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a three field record following this pattern:

```
(F1, May have CR) | (F2, May have CR) | (F3, No CR)CR
```

If F3 ever did have a CR, it would be ambiguous which record is which since you would not know whether the CR terminates the record or is embedded into F3 or the following F1 field.

You can easily parse what I have described with a regex in Perl:

```
$ perl  -e '
$str = do { local $/; <> };
while ($str =~ /^\n?((?:[^|]+\|){2}[^\n]+)/gm){
    $_=$1;
    s/\n/ /g;
    print "$_\n";
}
' /tmp/ac.csv
aaa|xyz|pqr
another|column with line break | last column
```

Which works by using a regex to separate the records from the stream.

[Live regex](http://regex101.com/r/iM4pR5/1) to show how that works.